# WebClient Http Post format parameters from illegal characters

Tags: c#, .net, http-post, webclient

I'm using the WebClient class to post a form, it looks like this.

```
string URI = "url here";
string myParameters = string.Format("Parameter1={0}&Parameter2={1}", var1, var2);

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
wc.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
```

Which works great, but certain characters like the `&` obviously breaks it.

How do I format my parameters to not remove but still make illegal characters get through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `UrlEncode` your `vars` using [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string URI = "url here";
string myParameters = string.Format("Parameter1={0}&Parameter2={1}", 
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(var1), 
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(var2));

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
wc.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
```

This will encode **all** illegal characters, not just `&`, BTW

---

when reading these, on the other side of the request, you'll probably need to also `UrlDecode` them [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: There was no issue with the decoding, atleast for the & characters. Or do you have any characters in mind that might require decoding?

Comment: suppose it depends how and where you reading the &. In some circumstances the framework will do the decoding for you.

Answer (score -1):

They need to be percent-encoded:

> encodeURIComponent('&')
>   "%90k"

For example the URL would look like:

www.facebook.com?service_name=M%90k